# Modification/packaging of firmware for TV motherboards based on MSD3663

Tags: firmware-analysis, binary-editing

Is it possible to somehow unpack or modify the firmware for the TP.MSD3663S.PB805 TV motherboard? For example, edit configuration files, graphic images or change them. What programs should I use for this? Binwalk unpacks, but gives me a bunch of empty .7z archives. Can this be done normally?